# SwiftUI UI testing Assets are not loaded

Tags: swiftui

So I'm trying to setup [Snapshot Testing](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing) and having some troubles with themes.

I have a view that takes colors from an environment theme. Here's a sample theme

```
private struct Phase1ColorTheme: ColorTheme {
    var id: String = "Phase1"
    var hexagonBackgroundColor: Color = Color("Phase1HexagonBackgroundColor")
    .... 
}
```

The view in question

```
struct InlineDropdown<T: Presentable & Hashable>: View {
    @Binding var optionSelected: T?
    var title: String
    var options: [T]
    
    @State internal var isMenuClicked: Bool = false
    
    @Environment(\.theme) internal var theme: any ColorTheme
    @Environment(\.spacer) internal var spacer: SpacingTheme

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: spacer.one) {
            Menu(content: {
               ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                    Button(
                        action: {
                            optionSelected = option
                            isMenuClicked.toggle()
                        },
                        label: {
                            Text(option.displayOption)
                        })
                }
            }, label: {
                HStack {
                    Text("Test")
                    Text("\(title): \(optionSelected?.displayOption ?? "")")
                        .foregroundColor(theme.textfieldForegroundColor)
                    
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(width: spacer.one)
                    
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                        .rotationEffect(isMenuClicked ? .degrees(180) : .zero)
                        .padding(spacer.one)
                        .foregroundStyle(theme.navigationButtonColor)
                }
            })
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .onTapGesture {
                isMenuClicked.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the snapshot tests

```
final class InlineUITests: XCTestCase {
    func test_inlineDropdownEmpty() {
        for theme in ColorThemeHelper.getAllThemes() {
            let dropdown = InlineDropdown(
                optionSelected: .constant(.one),
                title: "Test Title",
                options: TestValues.allCases
            )
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .environment(\.theme, theme)
                .environment(\.spacer, SpacingTheme())
            let view = UIHostingController(rootView: dropdown)
            assertSnapshot(matching: view, as: .image(on: .iPhoneSe), record: UITestsParams.recording)
        }
    }
}

private enum TestValues: String, Presentable, CaseIterable {
    case one, two, three
    
    var displayOption: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}
```

However the text isn't showing up in the screenshot test. Clearly in the image the Test text that auto chooses a color is getting rendered, so I know the view is there, but all the colors are nil, so it's invisible.

I've added assets to my UITest target, and copy the resources in build_phases

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this myself.

I created a class to load a bundle

```
class NormativeTheme {
    static var bundle: Bundle {
         return Bundle(for: self)
    }
}
```

then in my extensions

```
class NormativeColorTheme: NormativeTheme {
    // MARK: Text Fields
    static let textfieldBackgroundColor: Color = Color("TextfieldBackgroundColor", bundle: bundle)
    ....
```

This loads the assets